# How to prove that linear polynomials are irreducible?

Tags: polynomials

How would I prove that in a field, all linear non constant polynomials are irreducible? I know that $\deg(fg) = \deg(f)+\deg(g)$ and feel like this is something I need to use but not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be your linear non-constant polynomial. Then assume that $f$ is not irreducible. Then there exists $g$ and $h$ polynomials with smaller degree such that $f = gh$. But now, as you feel, $1 = \deg(f) = \deg(g) + \deg(h)$. There are only two options for this. Either $\deg(g) = 1$ and $\deg(h)= 0$ or the other way around. If $\deg(h) = 0$, then $h$ is just a constant. And remember that a reducible polynomial is exactly one that is the product of two polynomials of *positive* degrees.

Comment: In your last sentence say "a *reducible* polynomial is exactly one.. etc.

Comment: @coffeemath: Thanks for catching that.